# Cordova 2.9.0 how to install statusbar plugin

Tags: cordova, statusbar

Im using phonegap 2.9. Has anyone installed https://github.com/apache/cordova-labs/tree/plugins/statusbar? I cant figure out how to do it. Is it even possible in 2.9?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont't think so. From the [plugin.xml](https://github.com/apache/cordova-labs/blob/plugins/statusbar/plugin.xml):

```
<engines>
    <engine name="cordova" version=">=3.0.0" />
</engines>
```

Comment: thanks, upgraded to 3.x. I cant figure out how to install it in 3.x even? I can do the default plugins, but not these

Comment: @postnerd i have same issue. my statusbar notification is working in 2.2.0 but not in 2.9.0. what  should i have to change in my config.xml file. can you please help me